# ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre un ArrayList y un LinkedList?

Tags: java

Quiero modificar una clase `LigneBrisee` que contiene `Point` que representa una línea discontinua representada por puntos que utiliza tablas `ArrayList` para almacenar sus puntos. En efecto quiero utilizar `LinkedList` y por lo tanto ya no tienen un límite en su tamaño.

¿Tengo que preocuparme por el método que le dio el tamaño al tablero?  La variable `PointCapacity` o también `contains(Point p)` que me indicó si un punto pertenece bien a la línea discontinua o `nbPoints()` que me da cuantos puntos hay?

```
import java.util.ArrayList; // import the ArrayList class
import java.util.LinkedList; // import the LinkedList class


class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Point(int px, int py) {
        this.x = px;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
        this.y = py;
     }

    public int getx(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setx(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int gety(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public void sety(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isSameAs(Point p1, Point p2){
        if ((p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y)){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LigneBrisee l = new LigneBrisee(5);
        l.add(null);
    }

}

class LigneBrisee{

    private int maxNumber;
    private ArrayList<Point> pointsList;

    // Ecrire le constructeur d’une ligne brisee.
    public LigneBrisee(int maxNumber){
        this.maxNumber = maxNumber;
    }

    // Ecrire une methode add ajoutant un point a la ligne brisee.
    public void add(Point point)    {
        if (this.pointsList == null) {
            this.pointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        }
        if(pointsList.size() >= this.maxNumber){
            System.out.println("The list is full");
        }
        else {
            this.pointsList.add(point);
        }
    }

    // Ecrire une methode pointCapacity() et nbPoints() indiquant la capacite de la ligne brisee et le nombre de points actuellement sur la ligne.
    public int pointCapacity(){
        return maxNumber;
    }

    public int nbPoints(){
        return this.pointsList.size();
    }

    // Ecrire une methode contains indiquant si un point passe en argument est contenu dans la ligne brisee. Vous utiliserez pour cela une boucle for each et non une boucle classique.
    public boolean contains(Point p){
        for (Point point : this.pointsList){
            if (point == p){
                return true;
            }
        }  
        return false;
    }
}

class LigneBriseeLinked{

    private int maxNumber;
    private LinkedList<Point> pointsList;

    public LigneBrisee(){

    }

    public void add(Point point)    {
        if (this.pointsList == null) {
            this.pointsList = new LinkedList<Point>();
        }
        this.pointsList.add(point);
    }

    public int nbPoints(){
        return this.pointsList.size();
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p){
        for (Point point : this.pointsList){
            if (point == p){
                return true;
            }
        }  
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varias cosas:

1. En las colecciones, es mucho mas eficiente usar iterators(en este caso ListIterator), aunque puedes usar el forEach tal y como lo haces.
2. Si usas un LinkedList puedes usar el método contains(), para ver si el elemento está dentro de la colección.
3. Para saber el número de elementos puedes usar el método .size()

Con estos 3 puntos, tienes la respuesta a las 3 dudas que planteas después.
@Caldeiro te ha explicado la diferencia entre las dos colecciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sin embargo ya estaba usando `.size` cuando no estaba usando LinkedList. En particular, para comprobar que no excede el tamaño de la matriz en el método `add(Point p)`. es un error?

Comment: Es correcto, dado que estos métodos son comunes a todas las colecciones.

Answer (score 2):

- LinkedList permite inserciones o eliminaciones de tiempo constante utilizando iteradores , pero solo acceso secuencial de elementos. En otras palabras, puede recorrer la lista hacia adelante o hacia atrás, pero encontrar un puesto en la lista lleva tiempo proporcional al tamaño de la lista. Javadoc dice que "las operaciones que indexan en la lista atravesarán la lista desde el principio o el final, lo que esté más cerca" , por lo que esos métodos son O (n) ( n/4 pasos) en promedio, aunque O (1) para `index = 0.`
- ArrayList por otro lado, permite un acceso de lectura aleatorio rápido, para que puedas agarrar cualquier elemento en tiempo constante. Pero agregar o eliminar desde cualquier lugar menos el final requiere desplazar todos los últimos elementos, ya sea para abrir o llenar el espacio. Además, si agrega más elementos que la capacidad de la matriz subyacente, se asigna una nueva matriz (1.5 veces el tamaño), y la matriz anterior se copia a la nueva, por lo que agregar a un `ArrayList` es O (n) en el peor caso pero constante en promedio.

Resumen: Una arrayList te da mejor rendimiento y te permite buscar más rápido, en cambio una LinkedList te permite insertar/eliminar más eficazmente

Comment: Muchas gracias pero ¿Cambia esto la variable `PointCapacity` o también `contains(Point p)` que me indicó si un punto corresponde bien a la línea discontinua o `nbPoints ()` que me ha da cuantos puntos hay?